# PHPLot how to filter y axis label

Tags: php, phplot

I have this code:

```
$plot = new PHPlot();

//Define some data
$example_data = array(
     array('Learning',1),
     array('Reading',3),
     array('Writing',3),
     array('Oral Communication',1),
     array('Numeracy',2),
);
$plot->SetDataValues($example_data);
```

Now I get this graph:
[image]

My question is that How can I set the yAxis Text labels into static value like 1,2,3 and 4 only.. and not just like now 3.2,3,2.8,2.6 .. 2,1.8,1.6 ... 1, 0.8,... 0 .. ??

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the [`SetYTickIncrement()`](http://www.phplot.com/phplotdocs/SetYTickIncrement.html) method.

```
$plot->SetYTickIncrement(1);
```

Don't forget, there's also the [`TuneYAutoTicks()`](http://www.phplot.com/phplotdocs/TuneYAutoTicks.html) method.

Comment: question.. I add `$plot->TuneYAutoRange(4, 'decimal');` I hope it will display the y axis maximum of 4, but when I have value of the graph as 4, the yaxis label goes 1,2,3,4 & 5.. how can I set it that will only shows 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: Besides this being a completely different question than the one you posted above, have you had a look in the [documentation for `TuneYAutoRange`](http://www.phplot.com/phplotdocs/TuneYAutoRange.html)? There you can see that the arguments you're passing do not match the expected ones. Also as stated in the docs the method _is used to adjust the parameters ... when automatically calculating the plot range along the Y axis_. So range and labelling are two different pairs of shoes.

Comment: I see the ranging using `$plot->SetPlotAreaWorld(NULL, 0, NULL, 4);`